# Districts' names with state names as CSV with Overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I am looking district names of India with state names as CSV format.
I tried to write an overpass query but it is not working. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Is there any other simple query also I am looking only from Overpass API not from any other data provider.

```
[out:csv(::type,::id,admin_level,name,"name:en","country","admin_level_4_name")];

rel["name:en"="India"]->.rel;
map_to_area->.a;

(
    rel[admin_level=4](area.a)->.admin_level_4;
    rel[admin_level=5](area.a)->.admin_level_5;
    foreach.admin_level_5(
        out center ->.ctr;
        .ctr is_in->.admin_level_4_relation;
        .admin_level_5 set admin_level_4_name = .admin_level_4_relation["name"];
        out;
    );
);

out;
```

Comment: cross-post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/87936/districts-names-with-state-names-as-csv-with-overpass-api

Comment: @scai My intention was to get the attention by more users, If user base is same then there is no point.